# c++11 regexp and GCC

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 the regexp engine of the C++11 standard should be completed in GCC. Now, could someone explain me why this simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>


using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    string string_array[] = {"http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/",
                             "tcp://192.168.2.1:1234/hello/how/are/you",
                             "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1"};
    regex e("^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\\/{0,3})([0-9.\\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\\d+))?(?:\\/([^?#]*))?(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$");

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        smatch sm;
        regex_match (string_array[i],sm,e);

        for (unsigned i=0; i<sm.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << "[" << sm[i] << "] ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

results in this output (note for example the incorrectly parsed port number of the second line, but there seem to be many bugs)

```
[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/] [http] [//] [www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex] [] [regex_match/] [] [] 
[tcp://192.168.2.1:1234/hello/how/are/you] [tcp] [//] [192.168.2.1:1234/hello/how/are/you] [] [] [] [] 
[https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1] [https] [//] [mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm] [] [] [] [inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1]
```

while its python counterpart

```
import re

string_array = ["http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/",
                         "tcp://192.168.2.1:1234/hello/how/are/you",
                         "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1"]
e = re.compile("^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\\/{0,3})([0-9.\\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\\d+))?(?:\\/([^?#]*))?(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$");

for i in range(len(string_array)):
    m = e.match(string_array[i])
    print(m.groups())
```

correctly prints this?

```
('http', '//', 'www.cplusplus.com', None, 'reference/regex/regex_match/', None, None)
('tcp', '//', '192.168.2.1', '1234', 'hello/how/are/you', None, None)
('https', '//', 'mail.google.com', None, 'mail/u/0/', 'tab=wm', 'inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1')
```

I'm using gcc 5.3.0 on archlinux

edit:

I changed the program to this, checking the regex syntax_option_type flag

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>


using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    string string_array[] = {"http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/",
                             "tcp://192.168.2.1:1234/hello/how/are/you",
                             "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1"};
    regex e("^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\\/{0,3})([0-9.\\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\\d+))?(?:\\/([^?#]*))?(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$");

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        smatch sm;
        cout << "match: " <<regex_match (string_array[i],sm,e) << endl;

        for (unsigned i=0; i<sm.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << "[" << sm[i].str() << "] ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    switch(e.flags())
    {
        case regex_constants::basic:
            cout << "POSIX syntax was used" << endl;
            break;
        case regex_constants::awk:
            cout << "POSIX awk syntax was used" << endl;
            break;
        case regex_constants::ECMAScript:
            cout << "ECMA syntax was used" << endl;
            break;
        case regex_constants::egrep:
            cout << "POSIX egrep syntax was used" << endl;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and surprisingly I obtain at the end

```
match: 1
[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/] [http] [//] [www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex] [] [regex_match/] [] [] match: 1
[tcp://192.168.2.1:1234/hello/how/are/you] [tcp] [//] [192.168.2.1:1234/hello/how/are/you] [] [] [] [] match: 1
[https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1] [https] [//] [mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm] [] [] [] [inbox/15178022db56df29?projector=1] 
ECMA syntax was used
```

this really seems to be a compiler bug..

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/

Comment: `regex_match` requires a full string match, `re.match` only requires a match to be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @stribizhev Ok, but since regex_match returns true, like re.match (that returns a match object) what's the difference?

Comment: You have some other issue, the hyphen in your c++ regex `[0-9.\-A-Za-z]+` is properly escaped.

Comment: Well, I see nothing technically wrong with the C++ regex. It could span lines via some classes, but other than that, you are only using one string at at time so it should be ok. If the groups aren't being filled, that's because they don't happen to match the optional groups, but the whole regex succeed's. `"^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(/{0,3})([0-9.\\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\\d+))?(?:/([^?#\\r\\n]*))?(?:\\?([^#\\r\\n]*))?(?:\\#(.*))?$"`

Comment: @sin the problem is that [.\\-A] is interpreted as [.-A], so it matches any character in that range, included the ":" which is used to delimit the port number and the "/" which marks the start of the internal path

Comment: And since your regex is already anchored, you might as well try to use `if ( regex_search( str, regex ) ) {...}` because using boost::regex I get something different.

Comment: @sin I don't want to use boost, I was trying to use a new feature of the STL

Comment: That's not the problem, in C++ strings "\\" gets parsed to \. So "[0-9.\\-A-Za-z]" parses to [0-9.\-A-Za-z]

Comment: I hate to tell you this but the original C++11 _was_ boost::regex.

Comment: @sin run 'echo cia-o   | grep -e "[cia\\-o]"' and you will face the same problem, as opposed to 'echo cia-o   | grep -e "[ciao-]"'

Comment: That's command line parsing, has nothing to do with C++ strings. From your app, just cout  this source string  "[0-9.\\-A-Za-z]" where string str = "[0-9.\\-A-Za-z]";

Comment: @sin that's just because grep by default uses POSIX regex syntax, just like (apparently) C++11

Comment: Are you sure POSIX is the flags_default? I'm not sure about that, but you should change it to Perl or EMCA.

Comment: Boost claims the standardized default is _normal_. syntax_option_type ECMAScript, JavaScript, JScript, perl = normal

Comment: All of the constructors default to _normal_. Typical `basic_regex(const  charT* p, flag_type f = regex_constants::normal);`

Comment: @sin I checked the syntax_option_type flag, and surprisingly it is ECMAScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- [Match object `groups()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) vs. [`match_results`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/) difference
- Characters inside character classes should not be escaped

The [match object `groups()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) in Python returns all submatches (captured substrings) starting with Group 1:

> Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern.

The [`match_results`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/) starts enumerating all groups starting with the 0th group (the whole match):

> If successful, it is not [empty](http://www.cplusplus.com/match_results::empty) and contains a series of [sub_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/sub_match) objects: the first [sub_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/sub_match) element corresponds to the entire match, and, if the regex expression contained sub-expressions to be matched (i.e., parentheses-delimited groups), their corresponding sub-matches are stored as successive [sub_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/sub_match) elements in the `match_results` object.

The `\` in Group 3 is not escaping the hyphen, it is ignored thus creating a range between `.` and `A` (= `[.-A]` in a normal regex world).

**You cannot use escape symbols inside character classes in POSIX regex**, it is considered an error. Put the hyphen at the end to avoid the need to escape it (like `[0-9.A-Za-z-]+`).

So, in Python, use

```
e = re.compile("^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\\/{0,3})([0-9.A-Za-z-]+)(?::(\\d+))?(?:\\/([^?#]*))?(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$");
```

And in C++:

```
regex e("^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\\/{0,3})([0-9.A-Za-z-]+)(?::(\\d+))?(?:\\/([^?#]*))?(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$");
// ...
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    smatch sm;
    regex_match (string_array[i],sm,e);

    for (unsigned i=1; i<sm.size(); ++i) // Here, start with the second element
    {
        cout << "[" << sm[i] << "] ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Compare [Python demo](http://ideone.com/cuLRhI) and  [C++ demo](http://ideone.com/UObfQg).

Comment: Why you cannot use escape symbols inside character classes in C++ regex? Anyway I was aware of the fact that match_result does return the whole match, which is different from match.groups() which only returns the submatches.. That was not one of the differences that I was pointing out, the problem was the last you wrote

Comment: In POSIX, I corrected myself. Although I am still searching for reference. I thought ECMA syntax was used by default.

Comment: I also thought that the default was ECMA syntax, at least according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/, even though I understand that it's not an official information source

Comment: You can escape anything you want in a character class, but if it is a control code or a property construct, you don't get the literal. And ECMA is just javasctipt syntax, nothing there.

Comment: @sln: not in a POSIX bracketed expression.

Comment: Yeah, posix are classes, usually named, for comaptability in pcre for example. Does python use only posix expressions ?

Comment: I cannot get to the root cause, but the fact remains: the hyphen was treated as unescaped, and it created a range that  included `/`, resulting in  an overfiring.

Comment: @sln: You confuse the terminology. In POSIX context, POSIX character classes are `[:alpha:]` etc., POSIX bracket expressions are `[0-9]` etc. See [this terminology explanation here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class). In all other situations, I call `[0-9]` a character class, and `[:alpha:]` a POSIX character class (regular-expressions.info call it a POSIX bracket expression). BTW, Python does not support POSIX character classes.

Comment: Oh, btw, on the op's C++11 regex, the class in group 3 after parsing results in it being `[0-9.\-A-Za-z]+` passed to the engine. What do you mean by the hyphen is not escaped?

Answer (score 0):

The regex works right.

Change

```
cout << "[" << sm[i] << "] ";
```

with

```
cout << "[" << sm[i].str() << "] ";
```

and you see the correct result.

Comment: No, I do not see the correct result, the problem was the one pointed out by stribizhev

Comment: I test your example on vs2013 and get the wrong result you get at first. Then I change the line and see the correct string you aspect. But if you have resolve, it's ok!

Comment: To tell the truth, `sm[i].str()` is more correct than `sm[i]`, but it is just not the problem here, this part of code works alright.